# AWS S3 Notification Consolidation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

My goal is to develop an application that can check my AWS S3 bucket for *five files* and once achieved, kick off the Lambda function that loads these files into my database. Loading files from an S3 event is working well. The issue I face is that, even when you upload all files at the same time, each file generates a single event. My loading function gets kicked off five separate times.

I have some ideas on how to solve this issue. One approach is to consolidate the event notifications into one event. Is this possible? This approach would work because then I could have the process break if the client only uploads 4 files (and subsequently send an email saying to upload 5 files). Otherwise, in the event of 5 files, I can then kick off the Lambda to process everything in the bucket (if # objects in bucket = 5, of course! Which can be checked very easily.) This way, the Lambda function only runs one time.

In summary, I want the event notifications to be consolidated so I can run the Lambda function once instead of five times. Please advise if this is possible, and through which channel of AWS product I can find my solution in. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such concept as "event consolidation".

You will need to:

- Trigger an AWS Lambda function on *every* upload
- That Lambda function should first check that all 5 files have been upload
- If so, it can process the files. If not, it should exit.

The hard part is sending a notification if they "only upload 4 files", because this would require waiting sufficient time to allow them to upload the remaining file(s) before sending a notification. This would suggest using an AWS Step Function with a `Wait` so that it can check the files after a given period. The Step Function could be triggered on the first file upload (that is, when the above Lambda function sees only one file).